# PagedCollectionView Filter not reapplied after data changes

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, pagedcollectionview

I have a PCV created on a set of entities returned from a RIA services call.  Basic stuff.
The PCV has a filter property set.

When entites are changed (through a different feature of the UI) the PCV does not update --- there doesn't seem to be any evidence that the filter is being reevauated for the changed entity.

Do we have to reset the filter property manually everytime something in the collection changes to get the PCV to update the set of data it returns to the bound ItemsSource?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at these:
PagedCollectionView.NeedsRefresh 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview.needsrefresh(v=vs.95).aspx

and 
PagedCollectionView.Refresh
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview.refresh(v=vs.95).aspx